# Accessing API over url gives 404 error, accesing it over the IP works fine

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, cert-manager

I **added an SSL** certificate with cert manager to my cluster, and now I get an **404 error** when accessing it over the URL. When I access it with the **IP**, it works fine.
I am using **nginx**.

**Ingress-nginx-controller pod log**
when accessing over IP:

```
[08/Feb/2024:14:50:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 474 0.003 [btcapi-btcapi-service-80] [] 10.244.0.66:80 25 0.004 200 b8ad8a9e72f22a3cf7a72b602f5226c8
```

when accessing over url:

```
[08/Feb/2024:14:50:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 (scanner.ducks.party)" 212 0.000 [upstream-default-backend] [] 127.0.0.1:8181 548 0.001 404 681ce509b41db827657e2e45bda810fd
```

Let me know if you need any else information. Do not really know what to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, in my ingress I had this configuration error
Old ingress

```
  rules:
    - host: gtp.lunarlabs.me
    - http:
        paths:
```

you need to set a host but it did not get the host because of the "-" before the http  so I removed it and now it works fine